# Defining function weeklies(plants_d)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

> Consider a dictionary, `plants_d`, where the keys are names of plants,
>   and the values are descriptions of how often to water them. Search
>   through the entire structure for all plants that need to be watered
>   `"weekly"`, put them into a list, `sort()` the list, and return it.
>
> `plants_d` :: dictionary of plant names to watering instructions.
>
> Return value: sorted list of plants that need watering `"weekly"`.
>
> Test cases:
>
> ```
> >>> weeklies({'shamrock':'weekly', 'cactus':'monthly', 'rose':'weekly', 'succulent':'biweekly'})
> ['rose', 'shamrock']
>
> >>> weeklies({'fern':'weekly', 'shamrock':'weekly', 'carnation':'weekly'
> ['carnation', 'fern', 'shamrock']
> ```

I understand that I need to see if the `dict[i]== 'Weekly'` and then add it to a new list but I am not sure how. What I have tried:

```
     def weeklies(plant_d):
         plants = {}
         for in in plants_d:
             if dict{i} == 'weekly':
                 plants  = plants.append(i)
         return plants
```

Comment: *"I am not sure how"* - well every basic tutorial will cover using dictionaries, maybe start there?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did... well I think I have. I understand the concept of a dictionary, but how do you check if a value correlates with a key and return the key? That's the problem I am having. I can find the key and return its value but not the other way around.

Comment: note that the syntax for accessing an element from some dictionary is dict[key] and not dict{key}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
if dict{i} == 'weekly':
```

with:

```
if dict[i] == 'weekly':
```

Additionally replace:

```
for in in plants_d:
```

with:

```
for i in plants_d:
```

because "in" is keyword.

To avoid searching n times value from dictionary you should use items() function. It creates list of pairs from dictionary.
Then you can iterate over them:

```
def weeklies(plant_d):
    result = []
    for plant_name, description in plant_d.items():
        if description == "weekly":
            result.append(plant_name)
    return sorted(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it better now. Still slightly confused, but I will ask my teacher to go over it with me as well.

Comment: dict lookup is `O(1)` ... just fyi ... the complexity is the same either way